# How much does Ubuntu set apart from Lubuntu?

Tags: command-line, apt, lubuntu

I want to install Lubuntu on an old Laptop.
I want to work with python, so I have to use stuff like virtualenvs and so.
Therefor I need Terminal commands like `apt-get`.
Do these work similar on lubuntu and ubuntu??

Comment: Yes, the base system - apt-get, python, etc - is exactly the same in all derivatives.

Comment: Refer to: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu

Answer (score -1):

Lubuntu is basically a lightweight version of Ubuntu. It is designed for slower devices and uses the LXDE Desktop instead of Gnome (Ubuntu). It is also distributed with the apt package manager. Have a look at the official websites.

https://lubuntu.net/

https://ubuntu.com/

Comment: This is only partially correct; since 18.04 Lubuntu has used the LXQt desktop. Also, lubuntu.net is a fan website. The official website is lubuntu.me